# Finding height of BST for any node

Tags: c++, recursion, height, binary-search-tree

I was trying out code to find height of binary seach tree.I wrotte the code below:

```
 int height(node *root)
{
  if(root=NULL)
  return -1;

  int left=height(root->left);
  int right=height(root->right);
  return max(left,right)+1;
}
```

I inserted the nodes 5,17,34 and 2 into the tree and passed the root to height function.
Unexpectedly,the program got crashed and I had to force close the window during windows error reporting(I was trying in a IDE).I also tried this out in a online compiler but it also displayed runtime error.

the MAIN function:

```
  int main()
{
  node *root=new node();
  root=NULL;
  root=insert(root,5);
  root=insert(root,17);
  root=insert(root,34);
  root=insert(root,2);
  int x=height(root);
}
```

the INSERT function if in case you want to look at it

```
     node *insert(node *root,int d)
    {
      if(root==NULL)
      {
       node *temp=new node();
       temp->data=d;
       temp->left=temp->right=NULL;
       root=temp;

      }
     else
    {  if(root->data>d)
      {
       root->left=insert(root->left,d);
      }
      else
      root->right=insert(root->right,d);
    }
    return root;
   }
```

I want to mention that the problem started only when I tried to use the height function in the program.Before that,all the other functions had compiled and run successfully.I have tried dry run but cant figure out the problem.

Comment: You used `=` in place of `==`. Voting to close as a typo ([demo](http://ideone.com/5VWlSc)).

Comment: Looking carefully at the function,the value that is returned to a node is not its own height,but the height of its subnodes,The true height of the node can only be known by its parent node when the function adds +1 to the height while returning to the parent.In your case of height 2,the height is actually of its subnodes.The true height of BST will be returned to the main function,when +1 will be added at the end of the final function call.

Answer (score 0):

Use the max function. This function will return the height of the longest path which would be the height of the tree.

```
int main()
{

   int num = height(root);
   return 0;
}

int height (node * root)
{
    if(!root)
        return 0;

    return max(height(root -> right), height(root -> left)) + 1;
}
```